# Get TotalThickness value of IFCWALL element

Tags: c#, xbim

How can I get the `TotalThickness` value of `IFCWALL` element using Xbim.Ifc2x3?

As I can see it is contained in `wallElement.Material=>ForLayerSet=>TotalThickness`
or in `wallElement.IsTypedBy=>Material=>TotalThickness`
but when I try to access it by code it wouldn't recognize `TotalThickness` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just sum up all the thicknesses of material layers. But don't forget to check that the material is actually a material layer set as it might be other type of material.

```cs
var thickness = 
    (ifcWall.HasAssociations.OfType<IfcRelAssociatesMaterial>()
    .FirstOrDefault()?.RelatingMaterial as IfcMaterialLayerSetUsage)?
    .ForLayerSet?.MaterialLayers.Sum(l => l.LayerThickness);
```

You obviously need to add more null checking logic and probably inspect other possible types of `RelatingMaterial` as well.

Comment: It works! not for all walls, Some walls are null in HasAssociations but they have Total thickness threw the Material property like I wrote in the question. Do you have a way to get it threw Material?

Comment: You may want to try to get if from the related IfcWallType.

Comment: I managed with the BoundingBox, thank you!